# Малая галерея на странице товара

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, modx

Добрый день, пытаюсь на странице организовать небольшую галерею
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выводе страницы использую `onmouseover="onHover()" onmouseout="outHover()"`
Сами функции:

```
function onHover() {$('#item-bottom-img-main').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); }
function outHover() {$('#item-bottom-img-main').attr('src', $("#item-bottom-img-main-a").attr('href')); }
```

Но компонента this возвращает не сам объект вызвавший ф-ию, а Object. Если явно указывать id, то даже если применив данный id всем малым изображениям , будет работать только 1ая картинка с данным id

Comment: > _будет работать только 1ая картинка с данным id_ 
несколько картинок с одним id и не будут работать, покажите обработчики навешиваете

Answer (score 1):

Можно было просто в обработчик событий onmouseover отправить аргумент `this`
Т.е. у меня код стал выглядеть следующим образом: `onmouseover="onHover(this)"`